# why my images are not shown in home page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, console, backend

i just  upload my images  in  react app  and they were  shown at the  first  but  after  i  find  this error  and  they  are not   shown any more , they are already  saved  in mangoDb too ,  there  is  this  error   too   [Violation] 'setInterval' handler took 91ms  in infinite loop
[image]  ,  [image]  [image]    [image] [image]

```
import {
  MDBCarousel,
  MDBCarouselInner,
  MDBCarouselItem,
  MDBCarouselElement,
} from 'mdb-react-ui-kit';
import { Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import Product from "../components/Product";
import Message from "../components/Message";
import Loader from "../components/Loader";
import { listProducts } from "../actions/productActions";

const HomeScreen = ({match}) => {
  const keyword =  match.params.keyword

  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);
  const { loading, error, products } = productList;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProducts(keyword))
  }, [dispatch , keyword])

  return (
    <>
  
      <div style={{display:"flex", justifyContent:"space-between", marginTop:"40px"}}>
      <h3 style={{color:'GrayText' ,marginTop:"120px" , lineHeight:'35px' }}>Get more Style with <br/> Luckyou accessories! </h3>
      <MDBCarousel>
      <MDBCarouselInner>
        <MDBCarouselItem itemId={0}>
          <MDBCarouselElement src= "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518912217224-3b1ae276c89e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=756&q=80"  style={{borderRadius:"5px" , height :'450px'}}  fluid />   

        </MDBCarouselItem>
        <MDBCarouselItem itemId={1}>
          <MDBCarouselElement src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1450297166380-cabe503887e5?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=745&q=80" style={{borderRadius:"5px" ,height :"450px"}}  fluid /> 

        </MDBCarouselItem>
        <MDBCarouselItem itemId={2}>
          <MDBCarouselElement src=        "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1496345875659-11f7dd282d1d?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" style={{borderRadius:"5px" ,height :"450px"}}  fluid />
        </MDBCarouselItem>
      </MDBCarouselInner>
    </MDBCarousel>
    </div>
    
      <br/>
       <h4 style={{ color:"GrayText" , marginTop:"20px"}}>Summer style </h4>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader/>
      ) : error ? (
        <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>
      ) : (
        <Row>
          {products.map((product) => (
            <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
              <Product product={product} />
            </Col>
          ))}
        </Row>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

Comment: images missing inside the Product component, show as the Product component code and sample products json

Comment: please can u  explain  more ?

Comment: add your product component code

Comment: i already  did but i think that's  a problem of  api ,  they  were  shown  at the  first but now no

Comment: then check the API and check the result, check the value is coming inside `product.image` we cant help without relevant information

Comment: i added   a screenshot of server.js

Comment: No bro it is not engough. check what image value is coming in API response. you can check it in browser network, it is just right to the console in inspect

Comment: i added  another  screenshot ,  when  i  click  on image it show me  this message                 {"message":"Not Found - /uploads/image-1637501172769.jpg","stack":"Error: Not Found - /uploads/image-1637501172769.jpg\n    at notFound

Comment: Click on the first request with your API URL `products?keywprd=""` click on this and then the response. there you can see all the data which you received from API. and then if image URL is correct there open the above same request and check whether same server URL it is requesting to

Comment: i found  the  all  data   but  there is not an Url  , there is  just "image":"/uploads/image-1637500409768.jpg" , for  the information  bro  my  project is already  deployed  and  everything is ok i just got this error  , this is my app   https://luckyou-store.herokuapp.com/